# How to Install NginX + Flask + Webmin in Raspberry pi

Tags: python, nginx, webserver, raspberry-pi

I'm newbie to the Web server. I have never setup any server before.

I would like to write program in Python, HTML, Java Script and then put it into my raspberry pi and interact with it by using another computer in the same network with local network land.

Can anyone please help me. I knows very few about command line (I know basic things like app get , etc.) and would like to know how to install these (NginX + Flask + Webmin + SQlite) together and get it to run.

I have searched for many days and still don't have answer in this topic. It has only about Apache with Flask which is not what I want to do.

Thank you very much for your kindness

Comment: Question should be moved to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can install nginx with easyengine (http://goo.gl/Wzidcu).